# Наследование моделей Django, проблема с ORM

Tags: orm, django

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть 3 модели

```
class A(models.Model):
   ...

class B(A):
  ...

class C(B):
  ...

print A.object.all() # Выдает модели и B и С, а надо только А
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Модель **ORM** в **Django** организована так, что когда Вы создаёте модель наследованием от другой [неабстарктной](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/models/options.html#abstract) модели то поля родительской модели не копируются в дочернюю модель, вместо этого в БД в записи дочерней таблицы просто создаётся внешний ключ на запись в родительской таблице (сделано это сознательно из архитектурных соображений). Потому если запрашивать все объекты для родительской таблицы - будут находиться и записи относящиеся к объектам дочерних моделей. Потому нужно либо фильтровать объекты родительской модели которые относятся к дочерним, либо создавать [абстрактные модели](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4.X/ref/models/options.html#abstract) от которых наследовать как родителя (в этом случае модель «A») так и детей («B»).